# How to show a array of base 64 in a xpage?

Tags: file, base64, xpages

I need to display on the screen a file that is returned by a web service that is in the format of a base 64 array. The ideal was to display it in a new browser window. I built a java agent to consume the web service.

I think an output would be an xagent, but I never implemented one, I do not know if that's the way, and how I would do that. Would a button on xpage call the xpage that would execute xagent? How would you consume the web service? Calling the xagent xpage agent? Impior both the java agent code for xagent? I've been researching how to do this fun all day, but so far I have not had much success.

Thanks a lot,
Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XSnippet (of an XAgent) gives you a bit of an idea of what to do.
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=download-all-attachments

In the XSnippet above, all the attachments in a Document are being zipped and then sent to the browser as a zip file. 
The url has some parameters e.g. documentID which the XAgent uses to determine which document to zip through.
The XAgent gets a handle to the HttpServletResponse, and configures it so that, instead of sending back an XPage, it specifies it is sending an 'application/zip' file.

It then finds the document using documentId and zips it up, writes the contents to the response and then tells the facesContext that the response is complete (don't do anymore rendering).

In your case, you would put a parameter which identifies the file that you want download. And you could link to this XAgent using a url e.g.

```
Download.xsp?fileId=somefileid
```

Your XAgent would then setup the response similar to above but the content type might  not be an 'application/zip'. If you don't know the file type you can use 'application/octet-sream' but if you know it is a pdf of something you can use the appropriate [Mime Type](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Retrieve the file using whatever code you have written to access your webservice, decode it, and write it to the response's output stream

**Example Implementing in Java as a Managed bean**

The following example outputs some plain text that was originally in a base64 byte array. It is decoded and then written to the response.
All you would do is change the content type to 'application/octet-stream'

Create the managed bean in the Java Design Element.

```
package com.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.sun.faces.util.Base64;

public class DownloadBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DownloadBean() {

    };

    public void downloadFile() throws IOException {

        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext context = fc.getExternalContext();

        String myFileName = "SomeFile.txt";

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) context.getResponse();

        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        resp.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);

        // This example is just plain text but you would 
        // change this to 'application/octet-stream'
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");

        // Tell the browser it is an attachment with filename of <myFilename>
        resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + myFileName);

        OutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();

        // Somehow you need to get your byte[], 
        // that is up to you how you do that
        // This example has just used base64 encoding of 'Hello Marcus' 
        byte[] base64bytes = "SGVsbG8gTWFyY3Vz".getBytes();     

        // Option 1 : use sun.misc.BASE64Decoder to decode with Streams
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64bytes);      
        sun.misc.BASE64Decoder dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
        dec.decodeBuffer(bais, os);

        // Option 2 : use com.sun.faces.util.Base64 to decode to normal byte[]
        //byte[] normalBytes = Base64.decode(base64bytes);
        //os.write(normalBytes);

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        fc.responseComplete();

    }

}
```

Register it in faces-config.xml. Request Scope should be enough. so for example if you called it 'downloadBean', and it was of class com.example.DownloadBean, put this entry in faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>downloadBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.DownloadBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

**How to use**

You can then call this from a button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

    <xp:button value="Download" id="buttonDownload">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" 
            refreshMode="complete" action="#{downloadBean.downloadFile}">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

Or you can create an XPage like an XAgent that just downloads the file, and link to this Xpage in new window.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" 
    rendered="false" beforePageLoad="#{downloadBean.downloadFile}">    
</xp:view>
```

You could access url parameters if needed using something like 
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=get-url-parameter-using-java

Comment: Hello!

Thanks for the reply!

Here are some doubts:

I do not understand how I will trigger the xpage of xagent, can it be through a button?

Also how am I going to associate the byte64 that is returned by the java agent to xagent?

You say in your response to put as a parameter the file that I want to download. Actually I do not have a file but an array of bytes that I transform into base64. Is it possible for the java agent to display this array of bytes in the browser form in the content form of a pdf file?

Comment: yes you can trigger it using a button which uses 'open page' action, using the page of the XAgent. regarding the URL parameter I meant it would be a 'fileIdentifier' of some description to choose what file to get. if you have a byte array, you need to write it to the response outputStream, that is the part I left blank. check stack overflow for something like 'write ByteArrayOutputStream to response'. you may need to buffer it if it's a large file. if you don't like XAgent / SSJS, you can also do this from a Java managed bean method that is called from a button. let me know any more questions

Comment: Thanks a lot!
And how to integrate the java agent that consumes the web service with xagents?

Comment: If possible I suggest you forget about the Java agent, and instead move your code to a Java Design Element to be used with Xpages.
You could put everything in one managed bean.
Does this make sense to you? let me know if not

Comment: Ok, I'll try to implement as per your instructions. Another question, how do I integrate the agent I convert into a managed bean into xagent?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've updated the answer regarding managed bean. let me know how it goes

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you so much, but I have one more question. In what structure does the base64 of the managed bean return to the beforeRenderResponse event? I am very experienced in the classic development of Notes applications, however with the introduction of xpages many paradigms have been broken and I am having a lot of work to suit me.

Comment: no prob Marcus. the managed bean method doesn't return anything, it writes the base64 data to the outputStream.  I will update the answer with an example over the weekend

Comment: Hi Cameron!
I wrote the code as listed below. Entering the error below is displayed. But the permission entry java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader" already exists in the Domino policy file.

Comment: try
{
var externalContext:javax.faces.context.ExternalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response:javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse = externalContext.getResponse();
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","base64");
var outStream:java.io.OutputStream = response.getOutputStream(); 
DownloadFile.verArquivo()
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
facesContext.responseComplete();
}

Comment: catch (e) {
  print("Error : " + e.toString());
} finally {
  facesContext.responseComplete();
}

Comment: I've updated the answer with a working example of base64 data being delivered as an attachment download using Java only (no SSJS). as long as you replace the base64 byte[] with your data, and change content type to 'application/octet-stream' you should be ok. FYI I couldn't see any error message within your comments above so I'm not sure the problem you had with your SSJS code

Comment: Your code worked perfectly! I've tailored your code, and it includes calling the web service. In that case it does not return the byte array to me and does not give any errors. The strange thing is that consuming the web service of a java agent works. Are there any security restrictions? The web service has several classes, I imported all of them and rename them to the correct package name. Would it be better to generate a jar of these classes in eclipse and import them?

Comment: It is hard to tell what the issue is without seeing some code. In keeping with stack overflow guidelines, perhaps you could post as a separate question with some code and we can have a look. I don't think there would be a difference between java element and jar elements though.
Have I answered this question "How to show base64 from Xpages?" if so is it ok if you accept the answer?

Comment: Uhuuu worked!

Really, I agree with you. What I did was get the managed bean and put it in another application. It ran smoothly. How do I open the result in another window?

Another question, why did not work in the application I'm creating and worked in another that already existed?

I want to thank you for your patience and goodwill in giving me the excellent support to solve the problem.

Comment: No problem Marcus, without seeing the 2 applicaitons I can only guess the problem.
Do you have the 'Refresh Entire Application when design changes' ticked? (xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true) If you don't have this ticked then maybe you latest code changes are not taking effect. It could be as simple as that. Keep that one ticked while developing (needs a server restart to take effect), then also do project -> clean and then build twice to make sure latest is working. Just a guess though

Comment: Thanks a lot for tips Cameron!